# How to install jboss-eap-6.1.0.GA

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

I install jdk1.8.0 and i set the environment variable JAVA-HOME and PATH

I download the jboss-eap-6.1.0.GA(AS 7.2.Final)

I set environment variable JBOSS-HOME.

i located jboss-eap-6.1 in 'D' drive so i set JBOSS-HOME=D:\jboss-eap-6.1.

After all these run standalone.bat file. but i'm not able to install jboss server.

it gives a black screen and giving like

`JBoss EAP 6.1.0.GA(AS 7.2.0.Final-read hat-8) starting. ..`

After 1 hr also it giving like this only.

Not able to start the Jboss server

please give me a Solution for this.

Thank you

Comment: Try using jdk1.7.0_x instead and look what is in the `server.log` located in `JBOSS_HOME/standalone/log`, you might get more information there to why it is not working.

Comment: I think you mean `JAVA_HOME` and `JBOSS_HOME` instead of `JAVA-HOME` and `JBOSS-HOME`, right ?

Comment: `JAVA-HOME` is jdk path and `JBOSS-HOME` is D:\jboss-eap-6.1.

Answer (score 1):

According to RedHat's "[Supported Configurations](https://access.redhat.com/articles/111663)" document, Java 8 isn't supported.

There are some plans to add support of Java 8 to a 6.3.x or 6.4 version. (see https://developer.jboss.org/message/906154)

Comment: Java 8 is supported with JBoss EAP 6.3.3.